# WPF The Most Efficient Way of Loading Image

Tags: wpf, image, performance

May be this sound stupid but, which one is the most efficient way to load image?

**A**

```
BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
using(FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(source_path, FileMode.Open))
{
   bmp.BeginInit();
   bmp.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
   bmp.StreamSource = fileStream;
   bmp.EndInit();
   if (bmp.CanFreeze)
      bmp.Freeze();

   images.source = bmp;
}
```

**B**

```
BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
bmp.BeginInit();
bmp.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
bmp.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
bmp.UriSource = new Uri(source_path);
bmp.EndInit();
if (bmp.CanFreeze)
   bmp.Freeze();

images.Source = bmp;
```

I remember I read somewhere that loading from a stream completely disables the cache. If thats true, does it means loading from a stream is better in term on memory management?

Comment: You need to dispose the `fileStream` in case A eventually.

Comment: Can you measure it with StopWatch?

Comment: @usr yeah. Code updated.

Comment: @Reyn It would be safer to instantiate the fileStream in a [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement instead of explicitly disposing of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i have understood, when you load a BitmapImage by setting its `UriSource` property, the image is always cached. I don't know of any way to avoid this. At least setting `BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache` only ensures that an image is not retrieved from the cache, but it does not prevent that the image is stored in the cache.

The "Remarks" in [BitmapCreateOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapcreateoptions.aspx) says that

> When IgnoreImageCache is selected, any existing entries in the image
>   cache are replaced even if they share the same Uri

My conclusion from this is that caching is *only* performed when an image is loaded by an Uri. In other words, if you really need to inhibit image caching, you will have to load an image by its `StreamSource` property.

However, if this is really "better in terms of memory management" is perhaps worth an experiment. You could try out both alternatives and see if you observe any significant difference in memory consumption.

Comment: Thats why I'm ask this question. I've tried both method, yet not seen much difference. But, by the logic that using stream not stored image cache, I think It's should better in term of memory consumption

Comment: If you don't see a difference, you should always choose the "easier" solution, i.e the one with less code. I guess that's the UriSource one, because you do not need to deal with Stream objects.